# If $A^n = B$ and I know $B$, can I find $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are invertible, $p \times p$ matrices. If $A^n = B$ and I know all of the entries in $B$, can I find an $A$ for some or all integers $n \ge 0$? How many solutions for $A$ exist? If I'm thinking correctly, then $A = B * (A^{-1})^{n-1},$ but this is sort of self referential. Thanks!

Comment: Your question reminds me a well-konwn fact that [a positive-semidefinite matrix has precisely one positive-semidefinite square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Properties) though this does't answer your question fully, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1\\ & 1 \end{array}\right)$ and $A^{\prime}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} & 1\\ 1 \end{array}\right)$. Both matrices squared are the identity. Thus, if you know $A^2 = I$, you cannot determine (uniquely) $A$.

Comment: More generally, we can take
$$
A' = \pmatrix{1 & t\\0 & -1}
$$
for any $t \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it even when $p=1$, $n=2$: take $B=1$. If $A^2=B$, then maybe $A=1$, or maybe $A=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use diagonalisation of $B$ to constract a solution of this equation, that mean if $B=PDP^{-1}$ and we suppose that $D=Diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_k)$ if you put $A=PRP^{-1}$ where 
$$
R=Diag(\sqrt[n]{\lambda_1},\sqrt[n]{\lambda_2},\dots,\sqrt[n]{\lambda_k})
$$
So you can verify that $A^n=B$

Comment: Unless $B$ isn't diagonalizable, in which case you have to worry about finding the $n$th roots of Jordan blocks. And if $B$ has a repeated eigenvalue, the choice of $P$ may matter...

Comment: You should add that $\sqrt[n]{\lambda_i}$ cycles through every nth root.